# Hibernate Jpa - constraint violation exception on Primary Key(Sequence)

Tags: spring, multithreading, oracle, hibernate, jpa

I use Hibernate JPA in my application. I have a Table that has a Primary key(Sequence). Service inserts records to that table.

Version: Oracle 12c

Dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect

**Issue :**

We face problem(Unique constraint violation on SEQUENCE Key) during the load testing.

**Questions :**

1. This issue is not occurring all the time. But only during load test. Can someone please check and help to use thread safe generator?
2. Is it DB side sequence definition issue or at Java side?

**DB Sequence :**

```
CREATE SEQUENCE MY_SEQ    
START WITH 1
INCREMENT BY 1
NOMINVALUE
NOMAXVALUE
CACHE 30
NOORDER;

CREATE TABLE MY_TABLE    (  
    MY_PRIMARY_KEY INT default MY_SEQ.nextval NOT NULL,
    VALUE_COL VARCHAR2(10) NULL       
);
```

**Entity :**

```
public class MyTableEntity implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "MY_PRIMARY_KEY")
    @GenericGenerator(
        name = "mySequenceGenerator",
        strategy = "org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator",
        parameters = {
                @Parameter(name = "sequence_name", value = "SEQUENCE MY_SEQ"),
                @Parameter(name = "increment_size", value = "1")
        }
    )
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "mySequenceGenerator")
    private long myPrimaryKey;

    @Column(name = "VALUE")
    private String value;

}
```

Comment: First , `@Parameter(name = "sequence_name", value = "SEQUENCE MY_SEQ"),` - this  parameter contains two separate names: `SEQUENCE` + `MY_SEQ`. Second - according to the [Documentation of SequenceStyleGenerator](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/id/enhanced/SequenceStyleGenerator.html) there is no parameter named `sequence_name`, but there is `SEQUENCE_PARAM  - Indicates the name of the sequence (or table) to use.`, so I think you shouuld try: `@Parameter(name = "sequence_param", value = "MY_SEQ"),`

Comment: Pls post your Oracle version and the used Hybernate dialect. The probable explanation is that you passes a value of the PK in the `INSERT` which overrides the `DEFAULT` clause with `sequence`.

Comment: @Marmite Bomber, I update Oracle version and the used Hibernate dialect

Comment: Well you answered the question yourself. `Oracle10gDialect` doesn't support column `DEFAULT` with a sequence, that is available starting with Oracle 12. IMO your DB table definition doesn't correspondent with the Hibernate class. Either re-create the table using Hibernate auto or upgrade your Dialect.

Comment: The comment of @krokodilko seems to be relevant as well...

Answer (score 4):

### Oracle 10 Dialect

For **Oracle10gDialect** use this configuration

```
@Id
@Column(name = "MY_PRIMARY_KEY")
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
Long myPrimaryKey;
```

Hibernate creates a table and a sequence:

```
create table MY_TABLE (
MY_PRIMARY_KEY number(19,0) not null, 
VALUE varchar2(255 char), 
primary key (MY_PRIMARY_KEY))

create sequence hibernate_sequence
```

While storing it first gets the new sequence ID and than passes it in the `INSERT` statement

```
select hibernate_sequence.nextval from dual
insert into MY_TABLE (VALUE, MY_PRIMARY_KEY) values (?, ?)
```

### Oracle 12 Dialect

If you use **Oracle 12** that natively supports [`IDENTITY column`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/CREATE-TABLE.html#GUID-F9CE0CC3-13AE-4744-A43C-EAC7A71AAAB6) it is prefered to upgrade to **Oracle12cDialect** (note that this requires Hibernate 5.3)

Set the `strategy` to `GenerationType.IDENTITY`

```
@Id
@Column(name = "MY_PRIMARY_KEY", updatable = false, nullable = false)
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
Long myPrimaryKey;
```

The following table is created - the important part is `generated as identity` which provides the unique velues.
Note that no explicite `sequence` is required to be created, it is managed internally .

```
create table MY_TABLE (
MY_PRIMARY_KEY number(19,0) generated as identity, 
VALUE varchar2(255 char), 
primary key (MY_PRIMARY_KEY))
```

While storing **no ID is passed in the INSERT**, it is assigned by Oracle and returned to the session

```
insert into MY_TABLE (VALUE) values (?) RETURNING MY_PRIMARY_KEY INTO ?
```

Note that in contrary to the Oracle 10 you save one round trip to the database.

Comment: Detail about the implicite created sequence you may check in the dictionary view `select * from ALL_TAB_IDENTITY_COLS;`

Answer (score 0):

### Change long to Long

Because if you use long, it (by default) is 0. No generator is allowed to change existing values!

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/GeneratedValue.html