# How do I use Oracle 12c Automatic Identity Generation with Hibernate, Spring and JPA?

Tags: spring, oracle, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have defined my table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE MY_ENTITY (
  ID NUMBER GENERATED BY DEFAULT ON NULL AS IDENTITY
);
```

Using `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)` produces no errors.
After inserting some data with fixed ids manually and updating the sequence, I noticed that the ID's are not actually generated by Oracle. I updated the sequence like this:

```
ALTER TABLE MY_ENTITY MODIFY (ID GENERATED AS IDENTITY START WITH LIMIT VALUE);
```

How can I get Hibernate/JPA to use the Oracle 12c Identity generator?

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53922240/4808122) answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To use the Oracle 12c Identity Generation, use at least **Hibernate 5.3**. Example:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
  <version>5.4.4.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Your `application.properties` will need to provide the `Oracle12cDialect`.

```
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect
spring.datasource.platform=oracle
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostname:1521:MYSID
spring.datasource.username=MY_USER
spring.datasource.password=$ecret
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
```

Given a table with auto generated primary key:

```
CREATE TABLE MY_ENTITY (
  ID NUMBER GENERATED BY DEFAULT ON NULL AS IDENTITY
);
```

Use `GenerationType.IDENTITY` as strategy on the JPA entity.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MY_ENTITY")
public class MyEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    // the rest of your properties

}
```

To check if it's working, update your auto generated sequence with something like:

```
ALTER TABLE MY_ENTITY MODIFY (ID GENERATED AS IDENTITY START WITH 10000);
```

When inserting new entries, their ID's should be like `10001`, `10002`, etc.

Comment: Take note about your db is an **Oracle 12c**, your property jpa.database-platform is  **Oracle12cDialect** and your identity is a **NUMBER** in column **ID**.

Good response @chris, congrats.

Comment: DEFAULT ON NULL is critical here. Using id DECIMAL(19) DEFAULT my_sequence.nextval would not work.

Comment: @JRA_TLL How can I annotate the id field in order to get the exact ddl:GENERATED BY DEFAULT ON NULL AS IDENTITY? I want to use ddl-auto=create

Comment: @brsgrlr: Can´t tell, never used ddl-auto=create

Comment: @brsgrlr: ddl-auto=create is not recommended for production. I'd recommend using Flyway or Liquibase instead.