# Hibernate GenerationType.IDENTITY not generating sequence ids

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

In my springboot application, I noticed one strange issue when inserting new rows.

My ids are generated by sequence, but after I restart the application it starts from 21.

**Example:**

First launch, I insert 3 rows - ids generated by sequence 1,2,3

After restart second launch, I insert 3 rows ids generated from 21.  So ids are 21,22 ...

Every restart It increased to 20. - **This increasing pattern always 20**

**Refer my database table (1,2 after restart 21)**

[image]

**My JPA entity**

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
private Long id;
```

I tried some stackoverflow solutions, it's not working

I tried this, not working

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings=false
```

I want to insert rows by sequence like 1,2,3,4. Not like this 1,2,21,22, How to resolve this problem?

Comment: How did you create the table? Identity ID creation is a database operation and not performed by hibernate

Comment: What database engine do you use ? (Mysql, Postgres...)

Comment: [Identity cache](https://www.sqlshack.com/learn-to-avoid-an-identity-jump-issue-identity_cache-with-the-help-of-trace-command-t272/) could be the issue

Comment: If it's important to you to manage sequence you can use Strategy = GenerationType.AUTO. A specific table will be create to manage sequence.

Comment: @Mr_Thorynque `AUTO - either identity column, sequence or table depending on the underlying DB`. If sequence is desired, it should be specified explicitly with `@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO, generator="my_seq_gen") @SequenceGenerator(name="my_seq_gen", sequenceName="ENTITY_SEQ")`

Comment: @Mr_Thorynque I am using Oracle database.

Comment: @XtremeBaumer I am using @ Table annotation. Table will create automatically when I launch the springboot application. I don't know it created by spring or hibernate. I'm new to spring development

Comment: Never let hibernate generate tables for you. It is bound to cause problems because you don't have full control. You should drop that table and recreate it manually with `(START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 CYCLE CACHE 0)`

Comment: @XtremeBaumer I don't know where I need to use this. I will do research for this. Thanks for your inputs.

Comment: with a create table statement. maybe this is correct page: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/other-databases/nosql-database/21.1/sqlreferencefornosql/identity-column.html

Comment: Oracle manage id with sequence so may be that a Identity cache issue https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_6015.htm#SQLRF01314 by default cache size is 20

Comment: @Mr_Thorynque this is I want :) I try to figure out why it's increasing by 20. You got it. Thanks XtremeBaumer, for giving me valuable information.

Comment: It increases because the first time you run the application, it allocates IDs 1 through 20. Since you don't fully use them and the application perhaps doesn't properly close its connection, oracle still has them allocated. Then you establish a new connection which allocates the next 20 IDs. This goes on and on. To fix this, you have to manually create the sequence with `NOCACHE` flag

Comment: I strongly agree with @XtremeBaumer, do not let hibernate build your tables for you.  You can use what hibernate generates as a template, but it is bad idea in the long run.  The problems start to occur once your database is in production and you need to make changes to your database.  Hibernate will just change the database as needed and all data can be lost.  In general there are two database migration tools in java:  [Flyway and Liquibase](https://www.baeldung.com/liquibase-vs-flyway).

Comment: Please try allocationSize so that it won't get cached
@Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "my_entity_seq")
  @SequenceGenerator(name = "my_entity_seq", sequenceName = "my_entity_seq", allocationSize = 1)
  private Long id;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although I think the question comments already provide all the information necessary to understand the problem, please, let me try explain some things and try fixing some inaccuracies.

According to your source code you are using the `IDENTITY` id generation strategy:

```java
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
private Long id;
```

You are using an Oracle database and this is a very relevant information for the question.

Support for `IDENTITY` columns was introduced in Oracle 12c, probably Release 1, and in Hibernate version - I would say [5.1](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9983) although [here in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57767571/how-do-i-use-oracle-12c-automatic-identity-generation-with-hibernate-spring-and) is indicated that you need at least - 5.3.

Either way, `IDENTITY` columns in Oracle are supported by the use of database `SEQUENCE`s: i.e., for every `IDENTITY` column a corresponding sequence is created. As you can read in the [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/CREATE-TABLE.html#GUID-F9CE0CC3-13AE-4744-A43C-EAC7A71AAAB6) this explain why, among others, all the options for creating sequences can be applied to the `IDENTITY` column definition, like min and max ranges, cache size, etc.

By default a sequence in Oracle has a cache size of `20` as indicated in a tiny note in the [aforementioned Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/CREATE-TABLE.html#GUID-F9CE0CC3-13AE-4744-A43C-EAC7A71AAAB6):

> **Note:** When you create an identity column, Oracle recommends that you
> specify the `CACHE` clause with a value higher than the default of `20` to
> enhance performance.

And this default cache size is the reason that explains why you are obtaining this non consecutive numbers in your `id` values.

This behavior is not exclusive to Hibernate: please, just issue a simple JDBC insert statement or SQL commands with any suitable tool and you will experiment the same.

To solve the issue create your table indicating `NOCACHE` for your IDENTITY column:

```sql
CREATE TABLE your_table (
  id NUMBER GENERATED BY DEFAULT ON NULL AS IDENTITY NOCACHE,
  --...
)
```

Note you need to use [`NOCACHE`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/CREATE-SEQUENCE.html#GUID-E9C78A8C-615A-4757-B2A8-5E6EFB130571) and not `CACHE 0` as indicated in the question comments and now in a previous version of other answers, which is an error because the value for the [`CACHE` option](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/CREATE-SEQUENCE.html#GUID-E9C78A8C-615A-4757-B2A8-5E6EFB130571) should be at least `2`.

Probably you could modify your column without recreating the whole table as well:

```sql
ALTER TABLE your_table MODIFY (ID GENERATED BY DEFAULT ON NULL AS IDENTITY NOCACHE);
```

Having said all that, please, be aware that in fact the [cache mechanism](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/views002.htm#ADMIN11801) is an optimization and not a drawback: in the end, and this is just my opinion, those ids are only non natural assigned IDs and, in a general use case, the cache benefits outweigh the drawbacks.

Please, consider read [this great article](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/identity-columns-in-oracle-12cr1) about `IDENTITY` columns in Oracle.

The provided answer related to the use of the `hilo` optimizer could be right but it requires explicitly using the optimizer in your `id` field declaration which seems not to be the case.

Comment: Can I set NOCACHE from JPA annotation entity class?

Comment: Hi @Ranjithkumar. No, AFAIK it is not possible. As I tried to explain in the answer, you need to perform the change at the database level.

Comment: I thought the same. thanks for your feedback

Answer (score 2):

It is related to Hi/Lo algorithm that Hibernate uses for incrementing the sequence value. Read more in this example: https://www.baeldung.com/hi-lo-algorithm-hibernate.

This is an optimization used by Hibernate, which consumes some values from the DB sequence into a pool (Java runtime) and uses them while executing appropriate `INSERT` statements on the table. If this optimization is turned off and set `allocationSize=1`, then the desired behavior (no gaps in ids) is possible (with a certain precision, not always), but for the price of making two requests to DB for each `INSERT`.

Examples give the idea of what is going on in the upper level of abstraction.
(Internal implementation is more complex, but here we don't care)

**Scenario:** user makes 21 inserts during some period of time

**Example 1 (current behavior `allocationSize=20`)**

```
   #1 insert: // first cycle 
   - need next MY_SEQ value, but MY_SEQ_PREFETCH_POOL is empty
   - select 20 values from MY_SEQ into MY_SEQ_PREFETCH_POOL   // call DB
   - take it from MY_SEQ_PREFETCH_POOL >> remaining=20-1
   - execute INSERT                                           // call DB

   #2-#20 insert:
   - need next MY_SEQ value, 
   - take it from MY_SEQ_PREFETCH_POOL >> remaining=20-i
   - execute INSERT                                           // call DB
 
   #21 insert: // new cycle 
   - need next MY_SEQ value, but MY_SEQ_PREFETCH_POOL is empty
   - select 20 values from MY_SEQ into MY_SEQ_PREFETCH_POOL   // call DB
   - take it from MY_SEQ_PREFETCH_POOL >> remaining=19
   - execute INSERT                                           // call DB
```

**Example 2 (current behavior `allocationSize=1`)**

```
   #1-21 insert:
   - need next MY_SEQ value, but MY_SEQ_PREFETCH_POOL is empty
   - select 1 value from MY_SEQ into MY_SEQ_PREFETCH_POOL     // call DB
   - take it from MY_SEQ_PREFETCH_POOL >> remaining=0
   - execute INSERT                                           // call DB
```

**Example#1**: total calls to DB is **23**
**Example#2**: total calls to DB is **42**

Manual declaration of the sequence in the database will not help in this case, because, for instance in this statement\

`CREATE SEQUENCE ABC START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 CYCLE NOCACHE;`

we control only "cache" used in the DB internal runtime, which is not visible to Hibernate. It affects sequence gaps in situations when DB stopped and started again, and this is not the case.

When Hibernate consumes values from the sequence it implies that the state of the sequence is changed on DB side. We may treat it as hotel rooms booking: a company (Hibernate) booked 20 rooms for a conference in a hotel (DB), but only 2 participants arrived. Then 18 rooms will stay empty and cannot be used by other guests. In this case the "booking period" is forever.

More details on how to configure Hibernate work with sequences is here:
https://ntsim.uk/posts/how-to-use-hibernate-identifier-sequence-generators-properly

Here is a short answer for older version of Hibernate. Still it has relevant ideas:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5346701/2774914